# reading BMP header in Java

Tags: java, image, fileinputstream, business-process-management

I want to read the header of a BMP image so that when a person writes the path of an image bmp, it displays:

- the File size in bytes
- the Width in pixels
- the Height in pixels

I'm working on Java and the teacher suggested to use FileInputStream and FileOutputStream.

Comment: Since you haven’t shown us any of your code, it’s hard to know where to start explaining things.  Have you ever used those classes before?  Have you used the File class before?  Have you written a Java program before?  Do you have any information on the BMP format?

Comment: You didn't make any questions. What issue do you have?

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I want to read the header of a BMP image ..."*

Here is the *Wikipedia* article on the *Bitmap* image format, specifically the *file header* section.
*[Wikipedia – BMP file format – Bitmap file header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#DIB_header_(bitmap_information_header))*.

The byte offsets for width and height are *18* and *22*.

> *"... the teacher suggested to use FileInputStream and FileOutputStream"*

You can use the *[InputStream#readNBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readNBytes(int))* method to obtain the first *n* bytes of data.  In this case, *n + 4* since the last field is 4 bytes.

```java
try (FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("image.bmp")) {
    byte[] b = stream.readNBytes(0x32 + 4);
}
```

> *"... when a person writes the path of an image bmp, it displays:*
>
> - *the File size in bytes*
> - *the Width in pixels*
> - *the Height in pixels*
>
> ..."

You could utilize the *[ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)* class to convert the numeric values.

I am using the following *NASA* bitmap image.
*[NASA – SVS – Index of Frames Files for ID 13326 – frame_0001.bmp (3840×3840)](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/vis/a010000/a013300/a013326/frames/3840x3840_1x1_30p/360/frame_0001.bmp)*.

```java
try (FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("files/frame_0001.bmp")) {
    byte[] b = stream.readNBytes(0x32 + 4);
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(b.length);
    for (byte x : b) bb.put((byte) (x & 0xff));
    bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    String id;
    int size, sizeB, offset, width, height, planes, bpp,
        hSize, compression, image, h_ppm, v_ppm, colors, important;
    byte[] reserved1, reserved2;
    id = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 0, 2));
    bb.position(2);
    size = bb.getInt();
    reserved1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 6, 8);
    reserved2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 8, 10);
    bb.position(10);
    offset = bb.getInt();
    hSize = bb.getInt();
    width = bb.getInt();
    height = bb.getInt();
    planes = bb.getChar();
    bpp = bb.getChar();
    compression = bb.getInt();
    sizeB = bb.getInt();
    h_ppm = bb.getInt();
    v_ppm = bb.getInt();
    colors = bb.getInt();
    important = bb.getInt();
    String string
        = "b= %,d (0x%1$x), %s%n".formatted(b.length, Arrays.toString(b))
        + "id= '%s', %s%n".formatted(id, Arrays.toString(id.getBytes()))
        + "size= %,d%n".formatted(size)
        + "reserved1= %s%n".formatted(Arrays.toString(reserved1))
        + "reserved2= %s%n".formatted(Arrays.toString(reserved2))
        + "offset= %,d (0x%1$x)%n".formatted(offset)
        + "hSize= %,d (0x%1$x)%n".formatted(hSize)
        + "width= %,d%n".formatted(width)
        + "height= %,d%n".formatted(height)
        + "planes= %,d%n".formatted(planes)
        + "bpp= %,d%n".formatted(bpp)
        + "compression= %d%n".formatted(compression)
        + "sizeB= %,d%n".formatted(sizeB)
        + "h_ppm= %d%n".formatted(h_ppm)
        + "v_ppm= %d%n".formatted(v_ppm)
        + "colors= %d%n".formatted(colors)
        + "important= %d%n".formatted(important);
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Output

```
b= 54 (0x36), [66, 77, 54, 4, -31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 54, 4, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 1, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
id= 'BM', [66, 77]
size= 14,746,678
reserved1= [0, 0]
reserved2= [0, 0]
offset= 1,078 (0x436)
hSize= 40 (0x28)
width= 3,840
height= 3,840
planes= 1
bpp= 8
compression= 0
sizeB= 14,745,600
h_ppm= 0
v_ppm= 0
colors= 0
important= 0
```

Another approach is to use *[bit-wise and shift operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)*.